# Error when using the constructor of the class

Tags: c++, oop, constructor

I got 2 errors when I used the initialization list in my constructor.

first error: "no default constructor exists for class Shape"

second error: "member Shape::name is inaccessible"
My code:

```
class Shape
{
public:
    Shape(const std::string& name, const std::string& type): _name(name), _type(type){}

    virtual ~Shape();
private:
    std::string _name;
    std::string _type;
};
```

```
class Circle : public Shape
{
public:
    Circle(const Point& center, double radius, const std::string& type, const std::string& name) : 
        _center(center), _radius(radius), _type(type), _name(name) {}
    ~Circle();
protected:
    Point _center;
    int _radius;
};
```

Comment: `Shape() : _name{}, _type{} {}` would be a default constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comments inline:

```
class Shape
{
public:
    Shape(const std::string& name, const std::string& type): _name(name), _type(type){}
    Shape() : Shape("", "") {} // default ctor, delegating
    virtual ~Shape() = default; // better if you don't want to enforce implementing
                                // a dtor in every subclass

protected: // lifted from private if you need direct access from Circle
    std::string _name;
    std::string _type;
};

class Circle : public Shape
{
public:
    Circle(const Point& center, double radius, const std::string& type, const std::string& name) : 
        Shape(name, type), // use constructor of Shape
        _center(center),
        _radius(radius)
    {}
    // ~Circle() {} // not needed if base is default
protected:
    Point _center;
    int _radius;
};
```